# Cron job path for CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0, cpanel

I use shared hosting so I can't access to shell.

I have CronsController and i want to run index action of controller.
From cpanel I add cronjob like this:

```
php -q /home/mysite/public_html/app/crons
```

But this doesn't run the crons/index action.
How should I write path to my crons controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I write path to my crons controller?

You should **not** do that at all. If not properly protected *anyone* could trigger your controller from the web. Also that's not what a controller is made for.

**Use a shell** (or a shell command through cpanel for crons)

Assuming that the CakePHP core is in

```
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/
```

You should be able to run it like this:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/cake --app /home/mysite/public_html/app shellName
```

More details and examples are shown [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html).

Answer (score 5):

I run my CakePHP cron jobs like this:

```
curl --silent http://www.example.com/my_controller/my_action
```

So I guess you could use

```
curl --silent http://www.example.com/crons/index
```

EDIT: as burzum mentioned, running a cron job via a controller means that essentially anyone can type the URL of your conjob in their browser and run it, at any time. Depending on the nature of your cron job, this could be a security risk, and if so, you should use burzum's method.

Comment: how can i do this in a shared hosting like godaddy

Comment: I don't know how to do that off hand, and I haven't used godaddy before. A quick Google search yields this: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3547/creating-a-basic-cron-job

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is right or not, though it works for me

```
lynx -dump http://example.com/controller/action
```